# cant install plyr package via command line or manually

Tags: r, plyr

on typing

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

i get the following result:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/suraj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’
ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘reshape2’
* removing ‘/home/suraj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/reshape2’
ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/home/suraj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/scales’
ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’ are not available for    package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/suraj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/ggplot2’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpSWlplq/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
   installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

when i tried to install 'plyr' package by first downloading the plyr package and the using

```
install.packages("plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

i get the following message:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/suraj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.2, package 'plyr' requires R >= 3.1.0
Warning message:
In install.packages("plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
 installation of package ‘plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

install.packages("plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz",repos=NULL)
 Installing package into ‘/home/suraj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.2, package 'plyr' requires R >= 3.1.0
Warning message:
In install.packages("plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL) :
  installation of package ‘plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

plase can anyone guide me in this matter!

Comment: Your R version is 3.0.2 while to install the latest `plyr` you need a later version. Either upgrade R or try to install an older version of `plyr` from here: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plyr/

Comment: By the way, `dplyr` has superseded `plyr` for most uses, since 2014.

Comment: @smci While I think `dplyr` is a wonderful package, I don't think it could be of any help to install `ggplot2` (what the OP is trying to achieve)...

Comment: @nicola thanks sir version 1.8.1 work fine!thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Install version 1.8.1 of plyr from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plyr
and everything works like a charm thanks to @nicola for helping me on this one

For Windows, the appropriate version of plyr can be found in the [R 3.0 Windows Package Archive](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/).